# Kafka streams application doesn't scale with more CPU cores and threads on a single machine

Tags: apache-kafka, scalability, apache-kafka-streams

I'm writing a kafka-streams application which basically extracts 2 types of keys from avro records and counts them in the specified windows. It should handle ~6k events per second.

The issue I've faced with:

- one `c4.8xlarge` instance with `num.stream.threads = 20` threads (number of partitions the input topic) consumes only ~2.5k events per second
- same instance with `num.stream.threads = 10` threads consumes events with the same rate
- four `c4.2xlarge` instances with `num.stream.threads = 5` consume up to 10-25k events per second

I've never seen cpu utilization of any core higher than 70%. Network it underused also.

Here is my streams config:

```
kafka.streaming {  
  compression.type = "lz4"
  acks = 1
  retries = 1

  // I care about throughput more than about latency
  max.poll.records = 6000
  fetch.min.bytes = 3300000 // 6000 * 550 (average record size)
  fetch.max.wait.ms = 1000 // we get 6000 records in 1 second
  batch.size = 165000 // (6000 / 20) * 550
  linger.ms = 1000
}
```

Broker version: **0.10.2.1**

Kafka streams version: **1.1.1**

It seems surprising because I thought I can scale kafka processing linearly given there is enough partitions, no matter where consumers are located, on a single machine or on several ones.

Many EC2 instances can solve the scalability issue, but I would like to run my application on a single one because aggregations must be exposed through interactive queries and I do not want to develop an RPC layer.

**UPD: Stream definition**

```scala
signalStream
  .map[EventDetailsGroup, java.lang.Short]((_, v) => new KeyValue(extractEventDetailsGroup(v), Short.box(1)))
  .groupByKey(Serialized.`with`(eventDetailsSerde, Serdes.Short()))   
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(30 * 60 * 1000).advanceBy(60 * 1000))   
  .count(Materialized.as("store-name").withCachingDisabled().withLoggingDisabled())
```

Comment: So you report your number per thread? Or for the whole instance? How may brokers do you have?

Comment: Per instance. I have 6 brokers. Now I suspect that the bottleneck is RocksDB windowed store: when I reduce window size it processes data much faster. Also  put-rate is 2-2.5M. I think it's too high for my stream definition.